# web2py - Multiple Apps using same Auth

Tags: python, web2py

Here is a snippet from chapter 9 [Access Control](http://web2py.com/books/default/search/29?search=share%20the%20same%20auth%20database):

> If multiple apps share the same auth database you may want to disable
>   migrations: `auth.define_tables(migrate=False)`.

I have a setup where I would like to have each of my apps share the same user database but have own databases that are separate to the user DB.

Despite having skimmed through Access Control and [The Database Abstraction Layer](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer) documentation I didn't find an example of how to set this up.

Best I can tell I may be able to instantiate a new DAL pointing to the user database in each app, but I am unsure on how to point the entire Auth to that database and where to set `migrate=false`.

Something like inside of the App's `db.py` file:

```
auth_db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',
                  migrate=False)
```

and then maybe, a bit further down change:

```
auth = Auth(db, host_names=configuration.get('host.names'))
```

to:

```
auth = Auth(auth_db, host_names=configuration.get('host.names'))
```

I tried this and it did not work.

Clarification on the steps required to share the authentication between apps is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must indicate the location of the SQLite database, which can be done via the `folder` argument:

```
import os
auth_db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite',
              folder=os.path.join(request.folder, '..', 'otherapp', 'databases'),
              migrate=False)
```

where "otherapp" is replaced with the name of the application that contains the SQLite file.